# Manhua with the female lead being cast away by her husband, the emperor, and replaced with a saintess

Tags: story-identification, manga

Help me, I can't remember the name, obviously, but the female lead is divorced from her husband, who is the the emperor, and is sent to a deserted land. I think she either reincarnated or transmigrated, and she had a knight who originally was supposed to love the (evil) saintess, and a male aide who was also supposed to fall in love with the saintess.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour hair did the female lead and the saintess have?

Comment: female had brown hair i think and the saintess was a blonde